# Change where ReSharper add using statements

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When I use the "Add missing reference" feature of ReSharper Ultimate 2017.3 on VS2017, it adds the using statements at the top of the file, above the namespace. In my company we have these under the namespace, so I have to manually move them every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use ReSharper → Options → Code Editing → C# → Code Style → **Add 'using' directives to deepest scope**